# Logstash ConfigurationError - Expect character

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

i've this pattern that match correctly on https://grokconstructor.appspot.com :

```
"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}"\|"%{DATA:tz}"\|"%{GREEDYDATA:trans}\: %{GREEDYDATA:transId}"\|"%{GREEDYDATA:req}\: %{GREEDYDATA:reqId}"\|"%{IP:ip}"\|"%{GREEDYDATA:path}\=%{GREEDYDATA:codF}"\|"%{DATA:httpver}"\|"%{DATA:app}"\|"%{WORD:verb}"\|"%{GREEDYDATA:gw}\: %{GREEDYDATA:gw_status}"\|"%{GREEDYDATA:be}\: %{GREEDYDATA:be_status}"\|"%{DATA:unknown}"\|"%{DATA:postman}"\|"%{DATA:link}"\|"%{GREEDYDATA:tok}\: %{GREEDYDATA:token}"
```

When i configure logstash with this filter:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}"\|"%{DATA:tz}"\|"%{GREEDYDATA:trans}\: %{GREEDYDATA:transId}"\|"%{GREEDYDATA:req}\: %{GREEDYDATA:reqId}"\|"%{IP:ip}"\|"%{GREEDYDATA:path}\=%{GREEDYDATA:codF}"\|"%{DATA:httpver}"\|"%{DATA:app}"\|"%{WORD:verb}"\|"%{GREEDYDATA:gw}\: %{GREEDYDATA:gw_status}"\|"%{GREEDYDATA:be}\: %{GREEDYDATA:be_status}"\|"%{DATA:unknown}"\|"%{DATA:postman}"\|"%{DATA:link}"\|"%{GREEDYDATA:tok}\: %{GREEDYDATA:token}" }
    add_field => [ "grok_state", "match" ]
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> Failed to execute action
> {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main,
> :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of
> [ \t\r\n], "#", "{", "}" at line 10, column 61 (byte 158)
> after filter {\n  grok {\n    match => { "message" =>
> "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}"",
> :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in
> `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:182:in` initialize'",
> "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:72:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:48:in` initialize'",
> "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:50:in
> `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:386:in` block
> in converge_state'"]}

I tried to escape the `"` but have same error, any ideas?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Example of log:

```
"2022-11-28 09:14:59:514"|"+0100"|"transId: xxx"|"reqId: xxx"|"1.1.1.1"|"/path/codF=xxxxxxxxxxx"|"HTTP/1.1"|"SAP"|"GET"|"gateway status: 200"|"backend status: 200"|""|"Runtime/7.29.2"|"client"|"token: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

Comment: Are you sure `=> "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601` has a straight double quote and not curly quotes?

Comment: Yes, line start with `"2022-11-28 09:14:59:514"|"+0100"|.....`

Answer (score 1):

I solved, the entire block of the pattern must be enclosed in double quotes and double quotes escaped within the pattern:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "\"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\"\|\"%{DATA:tz}\"\|\"%{GREEDYDATA:trans}\: %{GREEDYDATA:transId}\"\|\"%{GREEDYDATA:req}\: %{GREEDYDATA:reqId}\"\|\"%{IP:ip}\"\|\"%{GREEDYDATA:path}\=%{GREEDYDATA:codF}\"\|\"%{DATA:httpver}\"\|\"%{DATA:app}\"\|\"%{WORD:verb}\"\|\"%{GREEDYDATA:gw}\: %{GREEDYDATA:gw_status}\"\|\"%{GREEDYDATA:be}\: %{GREEDYDATA:be_status}\"\|\"%{DATA:unknown}\"\|\"%{DATA:postman}\"\|\"%{DATA:link}\"\|\"%{GREEDYDATA:tok}\: %{GREEDYDATA:token}\"" }
    add_field => [ "grok_state", "match" ]
  }
}
```

Thanks all